# Get data from modalpopupextender's panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` and a column in `GridView` which has a `linkButton` that opens a `modalpopupextender` on click. I am able to bind data in `popextender` panel but now i want to retrieve data from that panel.
I am getting data from each `GridRow` like:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
 {                   
     Label Date = (Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("DateId");
     string date = Date.Text;
     //Code to get linkButton(asp:ModalpopUpextender) and data from  
     //asp:panel of ModalpopUpextender
  }
```

I have searched around for answers but wasn't able to find a solution to my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Abide for the useful post...finally i found the solution...

```
Panel.FindControl("ControlId");
```

does not work fine because somtimes panel is not added to the page.

we can use this code.It works fine.

```
foreach( Control cntrl in Panel.Controls ) 
{   
  if(cntrl.ID == "RequiredConteolId")    
   {
      //your application code goes here...
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are having a setup like this

```
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender 
            ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" 
            CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" Width="500px" style="display:none">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlCustomerDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerDetail" runat="server" Text="Customer Detail"  Width="95%" />

                </ContentTemplate>                
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You might try finding your  panel first and then drill down to  the required control.I would suggest putting this code in the row editing event

```
 gridViewTest_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {

gridViewTest.EditIndex=e.NewEditIndex;
Panel myPanel =    (Panel)gridViewTest.Rows(gridViewTest.EditIndex).FindControl("pnlPopup");
Label myLabel = (Label)myPanel.Findcontrol("lblCustomerDetail");
   }
```

//then do stuff with the label.

Comment: Great that you figured out the solution.Keep up the good work.